# Discrete mathematics: Question about finite automata

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have four questions about finite automata like these:

[image]

This is what I thought (I do not know it is correct or not):

(a) $L(M)$ is a set of strings which each of the string that the numbers of $1$ in the end is a multiple of $3$.

(b) $2$

(c) $5$

(d) I have no idea.

Can someone help me to solve these questions? Thank for your help.